# _viewContainerRef.createComponent(component) with Typescript Generics problem

Tags: angular, typescript-generics

I have a component open with angular-mat-dialog , and need to inject a component
iis that true

```
  @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data:{ RickIssue: any[],component:**ComponentRef<unknown>**
```

using type ComponentRef ?

---

other question is

```
   vcRef.createComponent(this.data.component);
```

createComponent need type **componentType: Type** ,how to fix this

```
export class ProjectDetailDialogComponent {

  @ViewChild(ProjectDirective, { static: true }) vcf!: ProjectDirective;

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ProjectDetailDialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data:{ RickIssue: any[],component:ComponentRef<unknown>},
  ) {}

  create(){
   const vcRef = this.vcf._viewContainerRef

   vcRef.createComponent(this.data.component);
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz-starters-gddaqz.stackblitz.io)

componentFactory in angular 16  deprecated thati didn't use